# Predicate Logic - Are these two sentences equivalent?

Tags: predicate-logic

Could you tell me if these two sentences are equivalent? If they aren't, what would be the correct sentence that is equivalent to (1)? Please explain. Thank you!

(1) (∀x)[Ax→(∃y)(By & Txy)]

(2) (∀x)(∃y)[(Ax & By)→Txy]

The expression that is supposed to be symbolized is "Every A takes at least one B".

Comment: Yes, they are. See [PNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Implication).

Comment: I'll check it out. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Answer (score 1):

The two are not equivalent. You want to change your second sentence to be

(∀x)(∃y)[Ax → (By & Txy)]

One way to see that your 1 and 2 are not equivalent is that under an interpretation in which there are some As but no Bs, then sentence 1 is false, but sentence 2 is true, because the antecedent of the material conditional in 2 is always false.

Comment: Uhmm, I see. But, what if now the expression to be symbolized is "Every A takes every B"...in that case, would (∀x)[Ax→(∀y)(By → Txy)] be equivalent to (∀x)(∀y)[(Ax & By)→Txy]? Would be correct to have an interpretation in which there are some As but no Bs?

Comment: That would work OK. Bear in mind that in predicate logic 'all' does not imply 'some', and 'all' statements are trivially true when there is nothing for them to apply to. So it is true that all unicorns love me, and also that I love all dragons. It is also true that all meerkats love all unicorns, which is an analog of your last sentence.

Comment: All right! Thank you!